# How to evaluate a buffer and print everything into another?

Tags: printing, emacs, eval

I've searched for hours on this and I have given up. Maybe you can help.

All I want to do is evaluate the LISP in a buffer and see everything that is printed. For example this here:

```
(setq NUMBERS (list 1 2 3))
(add-to-list 'NUMBERS 4 t)
(print NUMBERS)
```

So I did M-x eval-buffer and I don't see the Numbers printed. (Something not happening when using M-x M-e instead, but I don't want to this for every line and I also don't want to mark the region every time. I just want to eval the whole buffer). I looked up the description of eval-buffer and see that there is an argument for printing, but I can't give it any value because I don't know what to actually type in there. "print" maybe? But (universal-argument) only provides numerical values, so I'm lost.

Basic question: How to evaluate a whole buffer and actually see what is printed?

Answer (score 1):

This makes output appear in echo area for me in Emacs 27.1:

```
(print NUMBERS t)
```

even though the docs say:

```
Optional argument PRINTCHARFUN is the output stream, which can be one
of these:

   - a buffer, in which case output is inserted into that buffer at point;
   - a marker, in which case output is inserted at marker’s position;
   - a function, in which case that function is called once for each
     character of OBJECT’s printed representation;
   - a symbol, in which case that symbol’s function definition is called; or
   - t, in which case the output is displayed in the echo area.

If PRINTCHARFUN is omitted, the value of ‘standard-output’ (which see)
is used instead.
```

and `standard-output` is:

```
Its value is t
```